# Select SD mode on XTSD01G/XTSD02G/XTSD04/XTSD08G

Tags: spi, esp32, sd

I want to integrate an XTSD01G/XTSD02G/XTSD04/XTSD08G ([datasheet](https://atta.szlcsc.com/upload/public/pdf/source/20200525/C558837_DF3A234EC508088AA7895ED9F014713F.pdf)) memory chip, which should work like a SD card, with an ESP32-S3.

I want to use 1-line SD mode. In [this ESP32(-S3) guide](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/storage/sd_card/sdmmc/README.md) is described that I need a pullup resistor on D3 on the SD card. Also it does say that I need some other pullups. [This espressif SD guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/sd_pullup_requirements.html) says that the SD cards already have internal pullups.

The chip's datasheet doesn't contain documentation for application use and how to switch between SD and SPI mode. However, it does say it's a standard SD2.0 product. In the [SD2.0 spec section 8.1](https://datasheet.ciiva.com/18615/s-300u-data-sheet-sd-nxbw-rev101-18615264.pdf) it says, that the card can detect the mode itself. I suspect that this detection is based on the D3/CS pin. Low → SPI mode. And high or floating → SD mode?

What should I do with D3/CS? Should I place external pullups on the other pins?

Answer (score 1):

The SD protocol uses only 3 pins: CLK, CMD and Data line for a 1-line SD mode. The internal pull-ups are sufficient on the controller. The chip select pin can be left floating.